# Excel filter by range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am setting up a workout schedule. I have multiple rows with workout times, who is instructing the class, and who the class is suitable for. The suitable is a range, based on the following (anyone with martial arts experience will recognize this as belt degrees):

- 10. cup
- 9. cup
- ...
- 1. cup
- 1. dan
- 2. dan
- ...
- 9. dan

My spreadsheet has the following columns:

- Day
- Time
- Lasts
- Where
- Instructor
- Minimum belt
- Maximum belt
- Curriculum

Each class is suitable for someone within a range of the minimum and maximum belt. Now, I am trying to let the students easily filter out classes by simply selecting their degree from a dropdown at the top of the spreadsheet, and have only rows that are for them display.

Each instructor should also be able to easily filter out only the classes they teach, but I already know how to do that.

How would I do this?

Comment: I edited the last item in your first list - this shows how to escape Markdown parsing the period by placing a backslash before it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use Excel's Data Validation feature to create the dropdown list at the top of the sheet.  From there you could use a combination of INDIRECT() functions with named ranges that refer to lists of classes available for each degree.

For more information, check out this tutorial: http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html

Using this kind of setup will give you a dynamic table of class information.  Of course, you could make the entire table visible by creating an "All Classes" option in your dropdown menu.